# Создание моста + настройка принтера

Tags: windows, ip, wifi, mikrotik, принтер

Всем добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой. Есть небольшой офис, стоит микротик к нему подключен через Lan кабель МФУ. Нужно сделать так что бы МФУ Work Center 3025 по Wi-fi принимал сигнал и печатал с других кабинетов (кабинеты расположение далеко друг от друга до 30 метров и 3-5 бетонных стен, для этого нужны ретрансляторы). Можно ли купить роутер по мощнее и сделать по типу моста между роутерами (микротик и другим) что бы по WI-FI печатать ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

3-5 бетонных стен не берутся ретрансляторами. Купи mikrotik cap (какой - смотри по бюджету) и провод и возможно коммутатор. До каждого кабинета тащи провод и устанавливай там cap. Capы заводи в capsman и в основной бридж микротика.